# Send value from API request from a component to another Vue.JS

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

I have a component which allow to retrieve the datas from a rest API...
My template allow user to enter an input (id) and to find the user associated with the user. I also have a component which is called dynamically.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- form -->
        <form>
            <input type="text" v-model="userId"  id="userId">           
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @click="getUser($event); !isExistingUser">Get User</button>
        </form>

        <!-- result -->
        <div v-if="!showComponent">
            {{ user["id"] }} {{ user["username"] }} {{ user["email"] }} 
            <button @click="showComponent = !showComponent">Editer</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>

        <!-- Edit the user -->
        <div v-if="showComponent">
            <edit-user :toUpdate="updateUser"></edit-user>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the script part I have datas and methods : 
The objective is to send the user that i collect and to send it to the update user. For this I created a data binding.

I also try to set the value of the object in the getUser method. And i can display the value.

```
<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import EditUserForUpdate from "./EditUserForUpdate";
    export default {
        name: "FindUser",
        components: {
            "edit-user": EditUserForUpdate
        },
        data() {
            return {
                toUpdate: Object,
                user: null,
                isExistingUser: false,
                userId: "",
                userEmail:"",
                userUsername: "",
                showComponent: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            getUser(event) {
                axios
                    .get("http://localhost:4000/api/users/" + this.userId)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                        this.user = response.data.data;
                        var toUpdate = {};
                        toUpdate = { upUserName: this.user.username, upUserEmail: this.user.email, upId: this.user.id};
                        console.log(toUpdate);
                    });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Finally in the child component :

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "EditUserForUpdate",
        data: function () {
            return {
                updateUser: ''
            }
        },
        props: {
            updateUser: Object
        },
        methods: {
            beforeMount () {
                var updateUser = this.updateUser // save props data to itself's data and deal with it
                console.log("userToUpdate : " + updateUser);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My issue is that I don't retrieve the data in the child module for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

The property is named `toUpdate` and not `updateUser`.

Update your prop accordingly in the EditUserForUpdate component:

```
props: {
  toUpdate: Object
}
```

And of course, localize that object for manipulation:

```
beforeMount() {
  this.updateUser = this.toUpdate
}
```